# How to filter a list by hour

Tags: 2013, filter

I am on SharePoint 2013 and do not have access to Designer, as a preface.  I am trying to create a list view that filters items by whether or not they were added in the last hour.  I had done this earlier, only with items that were added in the current week, by creating two columns, 'Week Start' and 'Week End', and filtering by Created falling between those two.  Simple enough.  However, filtering list views does not allow for complex functions, nor does the [Today] function recognize time, causing an issue.  Is there any workaround for this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a calculated column and use the `HOUR` function, `=HOUR(Created)`

Comment: Thanks so much, I had been trying to use a Date/Time column and couldn't get some of my more complex functions to work.

Comment: [ViewMaster365.com/functions](http://www.viewmaster365.com/functions) is an up to date list of Functions & Syntax I compiled recently out of the (*sometimes incorrect*) resources on the Web.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new calculated column with `NOW()` function, as I show you in the following screenshot

[image: screenshot of new column]

Make sure you select "date and time" under "Data type returned"

This will return the current time, acording the regional settings of the server.